# PHP in_array() not working

Tags: php

I have a security token that is created when a page loads and writes that token to a file. Then I confirm that the token passed in the form matches one of the tokens in the file.

This first section is located in the FORM.PHP file, and I can confirm that the token is being written to the file.

```
//Create Token
$token = md5(time());

//Save token to file
$fp = fopen('/PATH/tokens.txt', 'a') or die ("Unable to open to Token file");
fwrite($fp, "$token\n") or die ("Unable to write to Token file");
fclose($fp);
```

This section of code is located in the PROCESS.PHP file. I have printed out the contents of the $tokens array and I can manually confirm that the same token is in there.

```
$tokens = file('/PATH/tokens.txt') or die("Unable to read file");

$token = $_POST['token'];

if (in_array($token, $tokens)){
   error_log("Found Token");
} else {
   error_log("Token Not Found");
}
```

I can't figure out why the `in_array($token, $tokens)` function is not returning TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `file('/path/file.ext',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`, otherwise every entry has the newline characters from the file appended.

Answer (score 2):

file() keeps the newlines character by default, which means you are matching a md5() to md5()\n.

To strip the newline character out, you need to pass FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES as a second argument to file()

Answer (score 0):

the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function will return an array with the newlines attached